# Why won't <INPUT> pick up my info when <P> can

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, input, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to get some input codes to update values based on a function elswhere.

The P areas work but I can't get it to work with INPUT.

Please see a photo below of this working.
[Working p's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dISX.png)

It's basically pulling out co-ordinates from google maps. 
I know the google maps part is correct as it's working with the P's.

I also intend in the future to make the input types hidden.
and remove the P altogether.

Please see below a photo of it working and updating in google developer tools as I click a map

All the p's below work

```
<!--    Map slot-->
<div id="map" style="Width:100%;height:350px;"></div>

<!--Lat and lng-->
<p id="location"></p>
<input id="location" type="hidden" name="location">

<p id="lat"></p>
<input id="lat" type="hidden" name="lat">

<p id="lng"></p>
<input id="lng" type="hidden" name="lng">
```

This is the marker bit in google maps I have that pulls it out.

```
<script>


function placeMarker(location) {

if ( marker ) {
  marker.setPosition(location);
} else {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });
}

document.getElementById('location').textContent = location.toString(); // get lat and long in 1
document.getElementById('lat').textContent = location.lat(); // get latitude
document.getElementById('lng').textContent = location.lng(); // get longitude
}

</Script>
```

Comment: FYI, `p` and `input` won't both work like you have it in the HTML because `id`s need to be unique and `document.getElementById` only returns a single node.

Answer (score 3):

`<input>` (`HtmlInputElement`) doesn't have a `.textContent` property because it doesn't have child nodes. Set the `.value` property instead.

Also your `id=""` attributes need to be unique in the page. Only one element can have each `id=""` value.

```
document.getElementById('location').value = location.toString();
```

Comment: I have tried this before and it doesn't work for some off reason. And it stops the P's from working. But many thanks.

I swapped all the .textContent for .value and got nothing

Comment: @AdamWatson No, don't change it for the `<p>` elements, only the `<input>` elemens. `<p>` elements still use `.textContent`.

Comment: Both the <P> and <Input> draw from the same id's, so if i swap to value, shouldn't the <inputs> just start working, and the <P> just stop?

How would i only change it for the input ones?

Many thanks

Comment: @AdamWatson You're using `id=""` incorrectly. **They must be unique**.

Comment: Well done!!!! Many MANY thanks.

Got lost in the value thing so the ID was pushed to the back of my mind.

Uploading answer now.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1

Change the textContent to value in the google map marker

Step 2

Give it new unique ID refs in your form

Step 3

If you delete the Ps, the inputs again stop working.
You have to also delete the google map part feeding the P's for the inputs to kick back in.

```js
  function placeMarker(location) {
    if ( marker ) {
      marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
//          Animation of marker
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
      });
    }
//    This gets the full lat and long
  document.getElementById('location').textContent = location.toString(); // get lat and long in 1
  document.getElementById('lat').textContent = location.lat(); // get latitude
  document.getElementById('lng').textContent = location.lng(); // get longitude
   
      //    This gets the full lat and long
  document.getElementById('location2').value = location.toString(); // get lat and long in 1
  document.getElementById('lat2').value = location.lat(); // get latitude
  document.getElementById('lng2').value = location.lng(); // get longitude

  
  }
```

```html
    <p id="location"></p>
    <input id="location2" type="hidden" name="location">
    
    <p id="lat"></p>
    <input id="lat2" type="hidden" name="lat">
    
    <p id="lng"></p>
    <input id="lng2" type="hidden" name="lng">
```